# How to update window in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, pyqt5

I am trying to write a depth first recursive backtracking maze generator with PyQt5. Functionally everything works fine, but not everything is implemented yet, so result may look strange :). I should say that I am quite new to Python and PyQt. I ran into a problem with graphics update. I would like the window to update the graphics based on the outcome of the algorithm which runs in a `while` loop in `go` function in App class. I did some research but nothing works. People tell me to just add line like `self.show()` or `self.update()` but none of this works.

I understand that I may have done something wrong conceptually, e.g. I should place some part of code somewhere else, or something like that. Or maybe there is some line or two to place somewhere to make it work.

In either case, please help me.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import math
import random
import pygame

w = 40
grid = []
qp = QPainter()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Cell(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        # super().__init__()
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.walls = [1, 1, 1, 1]  # top, right, bottom, left
        self.visited = 0
        self.currentCell = 0

    def index(self, i, j, cols, rows):
        if (i < 0) or (j < 0) or (i > (cols - 1)) or (j > (rows - 1)):
            return None
        else:
            return i + j * cols

    def checkNeighbors(self, cols, rows):
        neighbors = []
        if not (self.index(self.i, self.j - 1, cols, rows) is None):
            top    = grid[self.index(self.i, self.j - 1, cols, rows)]
        if not (self.index(self.i + 1, self.j, cols, rows) is None):
            right  = grid[self.index(self.i + 1, self.j, cols, rows)]
        if not (self.index(self.i, self.j + 1, cols, rows) is None):
            bottom = grid[self.index(self.i, self.j + 1, cols, rows)]
        if not (self.index(self.i - 1, self.j, cols, rows) is None):
            left   = grid[self.index(self.i - 1, self.j, cols, rows)]
        if 'top' in locals() and not top.visited:
            neighbors.append(top)
        if 'right' in locals() and not right.visited:
            neighbors.append(right)
        if 'bottom' in locals() and not bottom.visited:
            neighbors.append(bottom)
        if 'left' in locals() and not left.visited:
            neighbors.append(left)
        if neighbors.__len__() > 0:
            r = math.floor(random.uniform(0, neighbors.__len__()))
            return neighbors[r]
        else:
            return None


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 400
        self.cols = math.floor(self.width/w)
        self.rows = math.floor(self.height/w)

        self.init_cells()
        self.initui()
        self.go()

    def init_cells(self):
        for j in range(self.rows):
            for i in range(self.cols):
                cell = Cell(i, j)
                grid.append(cell)

    def go(self):
        current = grid[0]
        current.visited = 1
        current.currentCell = 1
        next = current.checkNeighbors(self.cols, self.rows)
        while not (next is None):
            next = current.checkNeighbors(self.cols, self.rows)
            if not (next is None):
                next.visited = 1
                next.currentCell = 1
                current.currentCell = 0
                current = next
            # I WANT TO UPDATE WINDOW HERE!

    def initui(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.lightGray)

        self.setPalette(p)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        for i in grid:
            self.draw_cell(i)
        self.show()

    def draw_cell(self, cell):
        x = cell.i*w
        y = cell.j*w
        # LINES
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 1, Qt.SolidLine))
        if cell.walls[0]:  # top
            qp.drawLine(x    , y    , x + w, y)
        if cell.walls[1]:  # right
            qp.drawLine(x + w, y    , x + w, y + w)
        if cell.walls[2]:  # bottom
            qp.drawLine(x + w, y + w, x    , y + w)
        if cell.walls[3]:  # left
            qp.drawLine(x    , y + w, x    , y)

        if cell.visited:
            qp.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 255, 100))
            qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)
            if cell.currentCell:
                qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0, 255))
                qp.drawRect(x, y, w, w)
        qp.end()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what that code is supposed to do. Maybe you should add some screenshots of what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: I will try to explain. Now you should see 10-by-10 grid with colored cells. Algorithm iterates along the cells starting from top left (always differently - random path) leaving unvisited cells gray, visited cells magenta, and current cell green. Finally it stucks having no more unvisited cells around the current cell, and this is the correct behavior for now. This is the state when it draws everything as a final result. Algorithm loop is the {while} loop in the {go} function. I would like to make it draw (or update) the grid graphics in (after) every iteration, so I can see it progressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a version of your script that shows how to do some simple animation using `QApplication.processEvents`, a timer, and sleep. I took the liberty of adding an F5 shortcut for starting a new run, and have tidied up a few other things:

```
import sys, math, random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QColor, QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QThread

WIDTH = 40
grid = []

class Cell():
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.walls = [1, 1, 1, 1]  # top, right, bottom, left
        self.visited = 0
        self.currentCell = 0

    def index(self, i, j, cols, rows):
        if (i < 0) or (j < 0) or (i > (cols - 1)) or (j > (rows - 1)):
            return None
        else:
            return i + j * cols

    def checkNeighbors(self, cols, rows):
        neighbors = []
        if not (self.index(self.i, self.j - 1, cols, rows) is None):
            top    = grid[self.index(self.i, self.j - 1, cols, rows)]
        if not (self.index(self.i + 1, self.j, cols, rows) is None):
            right  = grid[self.index(self.i + 1, self.j, cols, rows)]
        if not (self.index(self.i, self.j + 1, cols, rows) is None):
            bottom = grid[self.index(self.i, self.j + 1, cols, rows)]
        if not (self.index(self.i - 1, self.j, cols, rows) is None):
            left   = grid[self.index(self.i - 1, self.j, cols, rows)]
        if 'top' in locals() and not top.visited:
            neighbors.append(top)
        if 'right' in locals() and not right.visited:
            neighbors.append(right)
        if 'bottom' in locals() and not bottom.visited:
            neighbors.append(bottom)
        if 'left' in locals() and not left.visited:
            neighbors.append(left)
        if len(neighbors) > 0:
            r = math.floor(random.uniform(0, len(neighbors)))
            return neighbors[r]
        else:
            return None


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 400
        self.cols = math.floor(self.width / WIDTH)
        self.rows = math.floor(self.height / WIDTH)
        self.active = False
        self.initui()
        self.init_cells()

    def init_cells(self):
        if not self.active:
            del grid[:]
            for j in range(self.rows):
                for i in range(self.cols):
                    cell = Cell(i, j)
                    grid.append(cell)
            QTimer.singleShot(1, self.go)

    def go(self):
        self.active = True
        current = grid[0]
        current.visited = 1
        current.currentCell = 1
        while True:
            self.update()
            QApplication.processEvents()
            QThread.msleep(150)
            next = current.checkNeighbors(self.cols, self.rows)
            if next is not None:
                next.visited = 1
                next.currentCell = 1
                current.currentCell = 0
                current = next
            else:
                break
        self.active = False

    def initui(self):
        QShortcut(QKeySequence('F5'), self, self.init_cells)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.lightGray)
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        for i in grid:
            self.draw_cell(i)

    def draw_cell(self, cell):
        x = cell.i * WIDTH
        y = cell.j * WIDTH
        # LINES
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 1, Qt.SolidLine))
        if cell.walls[0]:  # top
            qp.drawLine(x    , y    , x + WIDTH, y)
        if cell.walls[1]:  # right
            qp.drawLine(x + WIDTH, y    , x + WIDTH, y + WIDTH)
        if cell.walls[2]:  # bottom
            qp.drawLine(x + WIDTH, y + WIDTH, x    , y + WIDTH)
        if cell.walls[3]:  # left
            qp.drawLine(x    , y + WIDTH, x    , y)
        if cell.visited:
            if cell.currentCell:
                qp.setBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0, 255))
            else:
                qp.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 255, 100))
            qp.drawRect(x, y, WIDTH, WIDTH)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It works great, and the F5 is a nice idea. However, I need to understand it fully, so let me check if I do: I don't understand what is the purpose of {active} flag, but I'm guessing it is for proper operation of F5 restart. {init_cells} function inits the cells into grid and then I am confused with the {singleShot}. From documentation I understand that it waits 300 ms and then it runs {go} once. If that is correct, why wait 300 ms? And what is the purpose of using it like that? I checked that replacing this line with {self.go()} also works.

Comment: @JacekWodecki. Yes, the `active` check prevents a restart while the animation is still running. I used a single-shot because otherwise (on my system) the window doesn't fully repaint when the script is first started. The 300ms is just a random number - probably 1ms would work just as well. Using a single-shot timer allows the event queue to be cleared before executing any further code. (PS: if you found my answer useful, please mark it as accepted - i.e. click the tick symbol).

Comment: @JacekWodecki. PPS: I made a few more minor improvements to my version of your script. Get rid of the single-shot if it doesn't make any difference on your system. The most important part of all the changes I made to your original script is the while-loop in the `go` method.

Comment: Allright, and tell me one last thing, what exactly is `QApplication.processEvents()` doing? I understand that it is sort of pushing the loop iteration into the events queue, but I think that is not very precise answer :)

Comment: @JacekWodecki. It forces the processing of all events waiting in the event queue (such as paint-events). The while-loop is blocking the event-loop, so the gui cannot be updated unless you do it explicitly.